# Smart Table st-sort Angular JS - Sort Not Working on Object of Objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, tablesorter

I am calling a service which returns object of objects something similar to this. userCollections is the variable that is being stored.

```
{
    1: {
        id: "A1",
        name: "B1"
    },
    2: {
        id: "A1",
        name: "B1"
    },
    3: {
        id: "A1",
        name: "B1"
    },
    4: {
        id: "A1",
        name: "B1"
    },
    5: {
        id: "A1",
        name: "B1"
    },
}
```

This is how I am displaying the data in the table.

```
<table class="table table-hover" st-table="DisplayCollection" st-safe-src="userCollections">
  <thead class="thead-inverse text-uppercase">
    <tr>
      <th st-sort="id" st-sort-default="true" class="cursor-pointer">Name</th>
      <th st-sort="name" class="cursor-pointer">Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody ng-repeat="(cname, cdata) in DisplayCollection">
    <tr class="cursor-pointer" ng-repeat="collection in cdata">
      <td ng-bind="collection.full_name | ellipsis:25:false"></td>
      <td ng-bind="collection.email | ellipsis:25:false"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

st-sort is not working. How do I make it work on object of objects.

I cannot convert the object of objects to array of objects, as I would need the object key for some operation.

Any way to achieve the sort?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript objects have no order and are not sortable.

Map your data to array and add the key as a property of each item

```js
var data = {
  1: {
    id: "A1",
    name: "B1"
  },
  2: {
    id: "A1",
    name: "B1"
  },
  3: {
    id: "A1",
    name: "B1"
  },
  4: {
    id: "A1",
    name: "B1"
  },
  5: {
    id: "A1",
    name: "B1"
  },
}
var newArray = Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
  var obj = angular.copy(data[key]);
  obj.key = key;
  return obj;
});
console.log(newArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
```